# "Unable to resolve class RemoteControl" with grails 2.3.7 and RemoteControl plugin

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to use the RemoteControl plugin in my current grails 2.3.7 project. I included it in the `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins {
   compile ":remote-control:1.5"
}
```

When I start the tests with `grails test-app` I get the error:

```
unable to resolve class RemoteControl@ line 12, column 18.
       def remote = new RemoteControl()
```

I use the RemoteControl in a *spock* test and I already executed `grails refreshDependencies` but I still get the error.

Any ideas to fix the problem? Shouldn't all classes from the plugin available at compile time?

Comment: have you tried running `grails compile` ?

Comment: Yes, but no luck. It compiles successfully. But what I´ve noticed is that during compilation the environment is set to ```development``` and during test-app to ```test```. Sounds reasonable, but could be there a problem in the test environment?